# specify string in title while using groovy template for play 1.2.5

Tags: playframework-1.x

I am using the groovy template for play 1.2.5.  I need to append a string to the title tag for the html page.  However, the option I tried below does not result in the value to be displayed - I am wondering whether the issue is related to escaping or faulty logic on my part (which I'm quite capable of).

```
#{set title:'ABCD | ${object.property}' /}  // object.property has a valid String value
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just figured it out - I did not need the ${}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While setting the title, the title is already within the "#{}" tag.  If passing another variable, one does not need to use the ${} format - simply ensure that you pass in the variable needed  without the ${} and outside the '' characters.  For instance:

```
#{set title:'ABCD | ' + object.property /}
```

This worked (as long as object.property is valid).  Unless I am mistaken, you can also use the 
object?.property format to avoid cases where the object might be null.  Hope it helps!